# Find infA when $A=\{\frac{m^2-n}{m^2+n^2}:m,n\in \Bbb N,m>2n>1\} $

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

$A=\left\{\frac{m^2-n}{m^2+n^2}:m,n\in \Bbb N,m>2n>1\right\} $

$\sup A=1$

$1$ is  upper bound:
$\frac{m^2-n}{m^2+n^2}\le1\\m^2-n\le m^2+n^2 \\ -n \le n^2 \mbox{ true}$

And for $n=1$,$ \lim \limits_{m \to \infty\ } \frac{m^2-1}{m^2+1}=1$

I suppose infimum A=3/5, because

$\frac{m^2-n}{m^2+n^2}\ge\frac{(2n)^2-n}{(2n)^2+n^2}=\frac{4n^2-n}{5n^2}$, and for $n=1$ it equals $3/5$, but I don't sure it. Could someone help me with $\inf A$? Thank you in advance.

Comment: $\frac{m^2-n^2}{m^2+n^2}=\frac{m^2+n^2-(n^2+n)}{m^2+n^2}=1-\frac{n^2+n}{m^2+n^2}<1-\frac{n^2-n}{5n^2}=1-1/5-1/(5n)=4/5-1/(5n)& hence the sup is 4/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One small correction I would make would be as follows. For all fixed $n\in\mathbb{N}-\left\{1 , 0\right\}$ we have
$$
\frac{m^2-n}{m^2+n^2}= \frac{1-\left(\frac{n}{m^2}\right)}{1+\left(\frac{n^2}{m^2}\right)}
\leq 
1
$$
and 
$$
\lim_{m\to\infty}
\frac{m^2-n}{m^2+n^2}
=
\lim_{m\to\infty}
\frac{1-\frac{n}{m^2}}{1+\frac{n^2}{m^2}}
=
\frac{1-\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(\frac{n}{m^2}\right)}{1+\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(\frac{n^2}{m^2}\right)}
=\frac{1-0}{1+0}=1
$$
His reasoning for the infimum needs more argumentation though you has posted the right answer. You need to argue that the function $\mathbb{N}-\left\{0,1\right\}\ni n\mapsto \frac{4n^2-n}{5n^2}$ is increasing.

Comment: This function is increasing because f(n+1)-f(n)>0, $\frac{(2n+1)^2-1}{20n^2(n+1)^2}>0$